# How to output notesSession.UserName without the CN=, OU= and O= in LotusScript?

Tags: lotusscript

How to turn *CN=Sample Name/OU=Country/O=Organization* To *Sample Name/Country/Organization*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this.

```
Dim n as New NotesName
Set n = session.CreateName( {CN=Sample Name/OU=Country/O=Organization} )

Print n.Abbreviated
```

More details on how NotesName works can be found here:.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESNAME_CLASS.html

Example:

```
CN=John B Goode/OU=Sales/OU=East/O=Acme/C=US
```

Would return:

```
John B Goode/Sales/East/Acme/US
```

Comment: Thank you for the example and the resource as well!

Comment: Any chance you could give an example of the value that n.Abbreviated would return based on the NotesName you supplied?

Comment: Click the link and look at abbreviated example.

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities:

First there is a property for that called `notesSession.CommonUserName`, but this ommits everything and just returns the common name part

If you have really need the abbreviated name, then the NotesName- Class is your point to start:

```vb
Dim myName as New NotesName( ses.UserName )
'common name
Messagebox myName.Common
'abbreviated name -> that's what you are looking for
Messagebox myName.Abbreviated
```

Comment: I think the link clinched it. ;)